# Simple Regex validation issue

Tags: php, regex

I'm usually pretty decent at regex but this basic one has me stumped.

```
  preg_match('/^(\+|-)\s+(month|week|year|day)$/i', '-1 month');
```

This is returning 0. Can anyone tell me why? It seems to be breaking on the `\s`.

Note: I have tried escaping the `-`.

Comment: Doh, nvm. I missed the numbers.

Comment: I would say: ^ That screams for a coffee break ? :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Indeed. Exactly what I am going to do. :)

Comment: When this happens to me... I just go to bed and solve the problem the next day. doesn't matter if it's 11:55AM. Go to bed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't account for digits:

```
preg_match('/^(\+|-)\d+\s+(month|week|year|day)$/i', '-1 month');
```